# Как убрать пустое пространство при переносе строки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

День добрый, не могу понять как сделать одинаковые отступы.
Есть несколько колонок, в каждой колонке 1 или 2 слова разной длины. второе слово всегда переносится на следующую строку, между этими колонками должно быть одинаковое расстояние, если делать через `max-width`, то есть пустое небольшое пространство в конце первого слова. возможно это элементарно, но я нашел пока только одно решение, заключать каждое слово в отдельный тег.

- 1) Мое решение
- 2/3) Проблема

```css
.directions-tabs-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__item {
  max-width: 150px
}

.directions-tabs-menu__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__text {
  letter-spacing: 0.52px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__order {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="directions-tabs ">
  <div class="directions-tabs-menu ">
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item " href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Управление</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">активами</div>
    </a>
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item " href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Управление активами</div>
    </a>
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item" href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Структурирование сделок</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

```
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте `directions-tabs-menu__item` или `directions-tabs-menu__text` свойство `width: min-content`.

```css
.directions-tabs-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__item {
  //max-width: 150px;
  width: min-content;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__text {
  letter-spacing: 0.52px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.directions-tabs-menu__order {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="directions-tabs ">
  <div class="directions-tabs-menu ">
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item " href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Управление активами</div>
    </a>
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item " href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Управление активами</div>
    </a>
    <a class="directions-tabs-menu__item" href="#">
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__order">02</div>
      <div class="directions-tabs-menu__text">Структурирование сделок</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```